# MonoDroid net.Sockets

Tags: .net, sockets, xamarin.android

im trying to build an android app which uses .net.sockets to conenct to a server and send/receive data from this.
The sending of data works fine, however when receiving it gives me an argument out of range error.
im not really certain what is causing this, a Windows Form Application with the same code works fine.
i hope somebody can help me.

this is my code:

```
            Android.Util.Log.Info("Starting Client", "Starting Client");
            TcpClient ClientSock = new TcpClient();
            ClientSock.Connect(ip, port);
            NetworkStream serverStream = ClientSock.GetStream();

            //sending command
            Android.Util.Log.Info("Starting Data", "Sending Data");
            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Heres Data");
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();
            Android.Util.Log.Info("Starting Data", "Receiving Data");
            //receiving data
            byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
            serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)ClientSock.ReceiveBufferSize);
            string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
            Android.Util.Log.Info("Return Data =", returndata);
```

i hope somebody can help me with this!

Comment: Have you tried (just for diagnosis) to replace (int)ClientSock.ReceiveBufferSize with a value of min(1000,size_of_server_message) ?

Comment: Tried that just now, no changes.

Comment: Please add the full exception message and stack trace and give us indication to which lines of code are related to it.

Comment: it gives an exception on:
serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)ClientSock.ReceiveBufferSize);
     
the exception is: Argument out of Range

Answer (score 0):

ClientSock.ReceiveBufferSize has nothing to do with the buffer you're passing in. Use inStream.Length as the third argument to Socket.Read.

Answer (score 0):

you can change inStream size to

```
byte[] inStream = new byte[ClientSock.ReceiveBufferSize];
serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)ClientSock.ReceiveBufferSize);
```

and in server class make shore from the same thing